# PowerShell Script To get Admins on Computers/Servers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will look through Active Directory and return a list of all the computers and servers with all the administrators on each of them. I have been mostly successful in getting the results I want, however if a PC/server is offline, I get an error that I can't seem to escape.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"} -SearchBase "OU=NAME,DC=domain,DC=com"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
        $admins = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $computer.Name `
            -Filter "GroupComponent=`"Win32_Group.Domain='$($computer.Name)',Name='Administrators'`"" `
            | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PartComponent `
            | ForEach-Object { $_.substring($_.lastindexof('=')+1).replace('"','') }
        Write-Output "$($computer.Name): $($admins -join ', ')"
    } catch {
            Write-Output "$($computer.Name): The RPC server is unavailable."
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting, it looks like the error comes before the output.

```
COMPUTER1: Administrator, Domain Admins
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:6 char:23
+ ...   $admins = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $compu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
COMPUTER2:
```

I'd like to see if formatted like this instead:
COMPUTER1: Administrator, Domain Admins
COMPUTER2: The RPC server is unavailable.

I have tried moving the try/catch around, but so far, the error persists. With hundreds of devices, this makes it very hard to read.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error means that you can't communicate with those remote hosts via DCOM. you can try using `Get-CimInstance` which uses a different protocol. other than that not much you can do other than ensuring you have the right permissions

Comment: If you want `Try..Catch` to work, you need to set the `-ErrorAction` preference to `Stop` on `Get-WmiObject`

Comment: Adding the -ErrorAction worked! Thank you.